# Sign email: is this code correct?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to digitally sign a MultiMIME message using the following code. I wonder if it is correct as I'm experiencing issues if the mails go through a Cisco IronPort email scanner. IronPort tries to remove the signature to append some additional info to the mail but it does not detect that my mails are signed. Therefore it just appends and the signature becomes invalid.
What makes me suspicious about my code is that the envelope for the signed message is set to "SevenBit" but the signature is attached Base64 encoded. But as it works (except the IronPort) issue I assume it is correct.

I can also see thet GetAlternateView() will return the trasfer encoding as "sevenbit" instead of "7bit". This is obviously wrong and was a known bug in .NET back in 2005 but shouldn't it be fixed by now?

So the question is: this piece of code below, is it really doing what it is supposed to do?
It gets called wiht the email oMessage being completely prepared and unsigned. Then

```
oMessage = this.Sign(oMessage);
MailMessage oMail.AlternateViews.Add(oMessage.GetAlternateView());
```

and the mail gets sent.

```
/// <summary>
/// Signs the contents of the specified envelope.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="oMessage">The mail content to sign. Can be null.</param>
/// <returns>An envelope which contains a signed mail.</returns>
private Envelope Sign( Envelope oMessage )
{
    Envelope oSignedMessage = new Envelope( "multipart/signed; boundary=\"" + this.sBoundary + "\"; protocol=\"application/x-pkcs7-signature\"", TransferEncoding.SevenBit );
    //oSignedMessage.Append( "\r\n" );

    // Open a new envelope which will contain the original mail content and the signature
    oSignedMessage.Append( "--" ).Append( this.sBoundary ).Append( "\r\n" );
    // Append the content to the new envelope
    // Can be null if no plain text or html content and no attachments.
    if ( oMessage != null )
    {
        oSignedMessage.Append( oMessage );
        // Don't need this anymore
        oMessage.Dispose();
    }
    oSignedMessage.Append( "\r\n" );

    // Create a second part in the same envelope for the signature
    oSignedMessage.Append( "--" ).Append( this.sBoundary ).Append( "\r\n" );
    oSignedMessage.Append( "Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-signature; name=\"smime.p7s\"\r\n" );
oSignedMessage.Append( "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n" );
oSignedMessage.Append( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"smime.p7s\"\r\n" );
            oSignedMessage.Append( "\r\n" );

// Create the signature..
byte[] aSignature = this.GetSignature( oMessage );
// ..and append it
oSignedMessage.Append( Convert.ToBase64String( aSignature, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks ) );
oSignedMessage.Append( "\r\n\r\n" );

// Close the whole envelope
oSignedMessage.Append( "--" ).Append( this.sBoundary ).Append( "--\r\n" );

    return oSignedMessage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been found. It was an additonal linebreak in the MIME content. MIME formats are very picky about linebreaks and newlines. One too much or one too less and you're screwed.
The other problem regarding "7bit" vs. "sevenbit" was that Microsoft's enumerator for the transfer encoding is called "SevenBit". At one place in the code "SevenBit.ToString()" was used which resulted in the string "sevenbit" instead of the enumerator value "7bit".

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's design problem. If IronPort modifies e-mails, it actually has no way to modify the signed e-mail and keep it's signature intact. It should either refrain from modification of signed mails or break the signature. I assume that IronPort (either via configuration setting or just hard-coded rule) chooses to modify the e-mail.

Comment: The issue is: up to last week I used a 3rd party component to send the mails. Up to then, IronPort detected the signature and removed it. Than it modified the mail. So the mail appeared to be unsigned to the recipient. Now IronPort seems to be unable to dectect that the mail is signed, modifies it and thus breaks the signature integrity. I cannot use the 3rd party component anymore b/c it does not habe 64bit support.

Comment: @krumelur if it worked before, then the solution is trivial - take the e-mail generated by 3rdparty solution and reproduce it with your code. Now you have the working code. Then start modifying your code until IronPort starts to break the e-mail. This way you will find, what exactly IronPort doesn't like.

Comment: Haha, I found the issue: it was one linebreak too much in the MIME content! Who ever invented that damn format should rot in hell! :-) SMTP is so "baaaah"! The additional linebreak prevented the envelope header to be interpreted correctly which resulted in the client (and also IronPort) assuming an incorrect encoding type.

Comment: @krumelur (a) extra line breaks do matter in some cases, and (b) you can accept your own answer above to mark the question accepted.

Comment: Yeah, I know but only after 24h.